# Grouping two types together

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I use a third party library over which I have no control. It contains 2 classes A and B, which both define a method with the same name:

```
class A {
    public:
        ...
        void my_method ();
};

class B {
    public:
        ...
        void my_method ();
};
```

I want to create a class C that contains a member which is of class A or B. Crucially, I can know only at runtime whether I will need A or B. This class C will only call the method `my_method`.

If I could modify the code, I would simply make A and B derive from a parent class (interface) that defined my_method. But I can't.

What is the simplest/most elegant way to create this class C? I could of course define C in this way:

```
class C {
    public:
         void call_my_method() { if (a) a->my_method() else b->my_method(); }
    private:
         A* a;
         B* b;
```

But I want to avoid paying the cost of the if statement everytime. It also feels inelegant. Is there a way I can create a super type of class A or B? Or any other solution to this problem?

Comment: Maybe using a template parameter as base class?

Comment: @MattiaF. The question says " I can know only at **runtime** whether I will need A or B"

Comment: Template will not work, because I only know at runtime if I need to call A or B.

Comment: Store function pointers in C?

Comment: What about wrapping A & B with another class?

Comment: "I want to avoid paying the cost of the if statement". Why? Is it something that measurably affects performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `std::function` (not sure it has better performance though), something like:

```
class C {
    public:
         void call_my_method() { my_method(); }

         void use_a(A* a) { my_method = [=]() { a->my_method() }; }
         void use_b(B* b) { my_method = [=]() { b->my_method() }; }
    private:
         std::function<void()> my_method;
};
```

Comment: I doubt a function call is going to be faster than a predictable branch? It's only a doubt though. Maybe this could be faster. It would need profiling.

Comment: I guess it would be faster in pipelined architecture, which is kind of every where now .

Answer (score 1):

No; at some point you need branching. The best you can do is to hoist the branching up/down the call stack<sup>†</sup>, so that more of your program is encapsulated within the figurative `if`/`else` construct and the branch itself need be performed less frequently. Of course then you need to duplicate more of your program's source code, which is not ideal.

The only improvement I'd suggest at this time is a construct such as `boost::variant`. It basically does what you're already doing, but takes up less memory and doesn't have that layer of indirection (using what's called a *tagged union* instead). It still needs to branch on access, but until profiling has revealed that this is a big bottleneck (and you'll probably find that *branch prediction* alleviates much of this risk) I wouldn't go any further with your changes.<sup>‡</sup>

<sub><sup>†</sup> I can never remember which way it goes lol</sub>

<sub><sup>‡</sup> One such change might be to conditionally initialise a function pointer (or modern `std::function`), then call the function each time. However, that's a lot of indirection. You should profile, but I'd expect it to be slower and harder on the caches. An OO purist might recommend a polymorphic inheritance tree and virtual dispatch, but that's not going to be of any use to you once you care about performance this much.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

How about using inheritance with a virtual function, using a 'base class' (C):

```
class C
{
public:
  virtual void do_method() = 0;
};

class D : public C, private A
{
  void do_method() { my_method(); }
};

class E : public C, private B
{
  void do_method() { my_method(); }
}
```

Then this will work:

```
C * d = new D();
d->do_method();
```

Comment: Now it's a function call _and_ a virtual table lookup.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There's no free abstraction.

Comment: @n.m. I realise that, but that doesn't mean you have to pick the most expensive one you can find :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Who cares, I'm reach ;) Unless there's a measurable performance impact on the application, choose the most expressive solution.

Comment: @n.m.: Yep and `boost::variant` usage is pretty dang expressive :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit maybe, maybe not. Depends. It violates the open closed principle and leads to tight coupling between object creation and uts usage.

Comment: Well, more importantly, the OP has no control over the classes so refactoring them into an inheritance heirarchy is out. You'd have to encapsulate the instances in something else. That's getting really unnecessarily complex.

Comment: A and B are unchanged with D and E wrapping around them

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to wrap your A and B objects into some helper template **TProxy** which realizes **IProxy** interface. Class C (or Consumer) will work with **IProxy** interface and won't know about type of the object inside **Proxy**

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A {
        void func () { printf("A::func\n"); }
};

struct B {
        void func () { printf("B::func\n"); }
};

struct IProxy
{
    virtual void doFunc() = 0;
    virtual ~IProxy() {};
};

template<typename T>
struct TProxy : public IProxy
{
    TProxy(T& i_obj) : m_obj(i_obj) { }

    virtual void doFunc() override { m_obj.func(); }

private:
    T& m_obj;
};

class Consumer
{
public:
    Consumer(IProxy& i_proxy) : m_proxy(i_proxy) {}

    void Func() { m_proxy.doFunc();}

private:
    IProxy& m_proxy;
};
```

**Main:**

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    TProxy<A> aProxy(a);

    B b;
    TProxy<B> bProxy(b);

    Consumer consumerA{aProxy};
    consumerA.Func();

    Consumer consumerB{bProxy};
    consumerB.Func();

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
A::func
B::func
```